# Refactoring dependencies instantiations in nodejs (expressjs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, coding-style, refactoring, node-modules

I want to refactor the following code into a more manageble and clearer codebase:

**FROM**

```
var express = require('express');  
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

**TO**

```
require('../loaders/routes.dependencies.js');
```

> where "../loaders/routes.dependencies.js" is a file containing the initially mentioned code.

**PS:** Feel free to correct the previous code as I'm still trying stuff..

> The objective is to clean the code from dependencies instanciating everytime on multiple files , there is a list of deps but I've made the most annoying case exposed here.

** PS **  Don't suggest any other types of refactoring ,I need this one in particular..thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From Node.js documentation :

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.
>
> Multiple calls to require('foo') may not cause the module code to be executed multiple times. This is an important feature. With it, "partially done" objects can be returned, thus allowing transitive dependencies to be loaded even when they would cause cycles.
>
> To have a module execute code multiple times, export a function, and call that function.

You should not be worry about "instanciating everytime on multiple files".

About your cleaning code solution, it's not a good idea to require one file with all deps that you're using at the moment, because your code will change in the futur and maybe you will work with somebody else on this project, so it's better to have your requires on the top of each file because it's more readable.

You can clean your code by separating your routes (express stuffs) from your custom functions to reuse them among all routes.

Comment: that's not what I'm asking for.
I've got a readability problem in my code which is going to be shared between team members and needs to be rapidly taken over so I don't want to surcharge the code with meaningless information , I'm thinking the way we separate business logic from the rest of the code but in a more radical way.

Answer (score 0):

**Savage , but works :**

```
var fs = require('fs');

// file is included here:
eval(fs.readFileSync('tools.js')+'');
```